# Apache won't accept connections from outside the network

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I'm attempting to troubleshoot an Ubuntu web server which will only respond to requests originated from the local network. I can use the domain name, external IP address, or internal IP address to get to the site, but only from *inside* the network.

The DNS records are correct on the registrar, they resolve to the correct IP address, the ports are open on the router, and the server is responding just fine to requests from inside the network.

For reference, my config files include the following:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ...
  <Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The web server is running Ubuntu 12.04 and Apache 2.2.

Comment: Are you sure the requests from outside are getting to the web server?  Do you have a tcpdump proving it?  If it isn't getting to the web server check DNS/firewalls.

Comment: Didn't know about `tcpdump` (today's 1 in 10k moment), thanks!

Comment: @echoback For that matter you can often save yourself the `tcpdump` if you have access logging enabled on your web server (if you don't see the requests they're obviously not reaching the server - though you'd still want to check with `tcpdump` from the outside to find out where they're getting lost :-)

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, there was no problem with Apache itself. Instead, my ISP is blocking traffic to port 80 from anywhere outside my own IP address.

Changing the ports in the `NameVirtualHost`, `Listen`, and `VirtualHost` directives to 8080 and requesting the site worked just fine. Since the router is set up to allow port 80 traffic to the server, the ISP is obviously the culprit.